# emit to specifics sockets (like a whisper) which contain specific socket.name

Tags: node.js, socket.io, underscore.js

I have my sockets stored like this in an object "people" . but now I would like to extract coincidences in people.name with an object like ["4323","9","43535"] for example 9.  meaning extract in this case "OGyF_FMFbsr0ldcbAAAK" socket.

In a few words navigate through   ["4323","9","43535"] and find if they are in people , so then emit a notification to the socket which contain people.name === 9 . Could be more than one socket.

So.

for each "attending"

```
["4323","9","43535"]
```

in "people"

```
{
 "ZA-CJOc1PtiwDVxkAAAD":
    {"name":"4","owns":"2-0-62","inroom":"2-0-62","device":"desktop"},
 "wKg2rcFSHgcl4m3WAAAG":
    {"name":"3","owns":"2-0-110","inroom":"2-0-110","device":"desktop"},
 "OGyF_FMFbsr0ldcbAAAK":
    {"name":"9","owns":null,"inroom":null,"device":"desktop"}
 }
```

then emit

```
 io.sockets.socket(id).emit("notification", result);
```

QUESTIONS:

How do I make the right code to select sockets to send notification?

How then would emit the notification for each one?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, then one way to do this is to iterate over the keys of your `people` object, compare the `name` properties of each of them with the elements in your `attending` array, and push any matching keys into a new array `found` to get a list of people whose name is found in your `attending` list.

You can then iterate over the `found` array to emit messages to clients in your `people` object that match your search criteria.

```
var attending = ['4323', '9', '43535'],
    found = [];


var people = {
    'ZA-CJOc1PtiwDVxkAAAD':  {
        'name': '4', 'owns': '2-0-62', 'inroom': '2-0-62', 'device': 'desktop'
    },
    'wKg2rcFSHgcl4m3WAAAG': {
        'name': '3', 'owns': '2-0-110', 'inroom': '2-0-110', 'device': 'desktop'
    },
    'OGyF_FMFbsr0ldcbAAAK': {
        'name': '9', 'owns': null, 'inroom': null, 'device': 'desktop'
    }
};


for (var person in people) {
    for (var i = 0, numAttending = attending.length; i < numAttending; i++) {
        if (people[person].name === attending[i]) {
            found.push(person);
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0, numFound = found.length; i < numFound; i++) {
    io.sockets.socket(found[i]).emit('notification', result);
};
```

### Edit

If you want to push whole objects onto your `found` array, you could do it like this. Since the entire object and not only the client id is being stored in the array, the emit loop below needs some slight adjusting to keep working.

```
for (var person in people) {
    for (var i = 0, numAttending = attending.length; i < numAttending; i++) {
        if (people[person].name === attending[i]) {
            found.push(people[person]);

            //this would give something like this, without the socket id
            //[{"name":"3","owns":null,"inroom":null,"device":"desktop"}]

        }
    }
}

for (var person in found) {
    io.sockets.socket(person).emit('notification', result);
};
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: If you want the entire object associated with the name found in `attending`, you could `found.push(people[person])` instead and it should do what you need.

Comment: @Miguel This will change the way you have to emit your notifications below that, though.

Comment: @Miguel No worries! I edited my answer to include a demonstration of how you might implement those changes to make sure it still works.

Comment: Although, thinking about it, using `for-in` loops to iterate over the elements of an array is bad practice. This is something you'll probably want to play with.